# I need for the PendingIntent to open up different Activities depending on the type of notification that the user receives

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

When a user receives a message from another user they get a notification from the `Firebase Cloud Messaging` system. When the user clicks on that notification, it takes them to the `MessageActivity` which is great.

I have a few other instances where a user receives one of these `Firebase Cloud Messaging` notifications: when someone comments on your posts, likes your post, etc. When they receives those notifications obviously it should take them to the `PostActivity`, and not the `MessageActivity`.

So, should I write another `"MyFirebaseInstanceServiceActivity"` or can I just do some simple change so that if it's a comment notification it takes you to the `PostActivity` instead of the `MessageActivity`?

**MyFirebaseInstanceService**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String sented = remoteMessage.getData().get("sented");

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null && sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseInstanceService.this, MessageActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyFirebaseInstanceService.this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyFirebaseInstanceService.this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_events);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(body);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSound(sound);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        int i = 0;
        if (j > 0)
            i = j;

        notificationManager.notify(i, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.d("TOKEN", s);

        Task<InstanceIdResult> task = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(instanceIdResult -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                sendRegistrationToServer(token);
                Log.d("TOKEN", token);
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Exception exception = task.getException();
                Log.d("TOKEN", exception.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
            Token token1 = new Token(token);
            reference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(token1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple check will do the job, you need to send some data that you check to know if the notification comes from comment or like or post  or whatever

```
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    .....
String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
String nType= remoteMessage.getData().get("type");// here type is some data you send
int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    ...
Intent intent = null;
PendingIntent pendingIntent=null;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    if(nType.equals("message")){
        intent=new Intent(MyFirebaseInstanceService.this, MessageActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// here you can change launch mode if you want
        bundle.putString("id", "124");// here add your data to the bundle
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyFirebaseInstanceService.this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    }else  if(nType.equals("comment")){
        intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseInstanceService.this, PostActivity.class);
        bundle.putString("postId", "134");// here add your data to the bundle
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        // here You may need to user TaskStackBuilder  so if the user click back from PostActivity it goes to MessageActivity
        TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MyFirebaseInstanceService.this);
        taskStackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
        pendingIntent = taskStackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
  .....
}
```

here is a link to how to use [TaskStackBuilder](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation)